# Guzzle 3 not sending POST request

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 3, as it's the only version that works on PHP 5.3.2.

I'm having problems sending a POST request, and it appears it's not actually sending the post data. The API works fine. I am able to use Postman to get results when using the correct API key and user ID, but from my script I am not.

What am I doing wrong? I am following the Guzzle documentation:

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client("http://example.com/api");

# Make API request to get session data
$request = $client->post('user/session', array(
    'body' => array(
        'token' => $_SESSION['ER']['API_KEY'],
        'user' => $_SESSION['ER']['USER_ID']
    )
));

$response = $request->send();

var_dump($_SESSION['ER']['API_KEY']);
var_dump($_SESSION['ER']['USER_ID']);

\\ string(32) "a559d5bba5a9e9517d5c3ed7aeb62db6"
\\ string(5) "30972"
```

When I `var_dump` `$_POST['token']` on the API, it's not even set. Yet if I run the request in Postman, it works.

Any advice on this please? I am really struggling to see what I'm doing wrong with this request.

Comment: What does the response object look like?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and fixed it by calling post like:

```
$request = $client->post(
    'user/session', 
    // this is array of headers
    null, 
    // this is dedicated field with body to post
    array(
        'token' => $_SESSION['ER']['API_KEY'],
        'user' => $_SESSION['ER']['USER_ID']
    )
));
```

Comment: I still have the problem that client calls in GET (using PHP 5.3.28)